# jquery tab click open new page without ajax request

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using below code for create TAB

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>Master</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/articleposting"><span>Posting</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/deal"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-1">
        <div id="vtabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/category"><span>Categories</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/user"><span>Users</span></a></li>        
    </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({ ajaxOptions: { async: false},remote: true });
});
```

I want to open a new page in same window and don't want to use TAB plugin ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem using jQuery load function

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>Master</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#articleposting" data-url="/articleposting"><span>Posting</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-1">
        <div id="vtabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#category" data-url="/category"><span>Categories</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

then read the data-url attribute & get the response using jquery's  Load method into parent container

```
$('#parentContainer').load(
....

....
)
```